# Black image when creating a Bitmap from a selection of the screen in C++

Tags: c++, winapi, screenshot, bmp

I am trying to get a screen capture of a selected region of the desktop.

The problem I am having is that the output (.bmp file) is just black.

I took CreateBitmapInfoStruct(); and CreateBMPFile(); from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145119%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The rest has been snips from the internet Frankenstein-ed together by me.

Here is what my code looks like presently:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

PBITMAPINFO CreateBitmapInfoStruct(HBITMAP hBmp)
{ 
    BITMAP bmp; 
    PBITMAPINFO pbmi; 
    WORD    cClrBits; 

    // Retrieve the bitmap color format, width, and height.  
    if (!GetObject(hBmp, sizeof(BITMAP), (LPSTR)&bmp)) 
        cout << "ERROR:1";

    // Convert the color format to a count of bits.  
    cClrBits = (WORD)(bmp.bmPlanes * bmp.bmBitsPixel); 
    if (cClrBits == 1) 
        cClrBits = 1; 
    else if (cClrBits <= 4) 
        cClrBits = 4; 
    else if (cClrBits <= 8) 
        cClrBits = 8; 
    else if (cClrBits <= 16) 
        cClrBits = 16; 
    else if (cClrBits <= 24) 
        cClrBits = 24; 
    else cClrBits = 32; 

    // Allocate memory for the BITMAPINFO structure. (This structure  
    // contains a BITMAPINFOHEADER structure and an array of RGBQUAD  
    // data structures.)  

     if (cClrBits < 24) 
         pbmi = (PBITMAPINFO) LocalAlloc(LPTR, 
                    sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER) + 
                    sizeof(RGBQUAD) * (1<< cClrBits)); 

     // There is no RGBQUAD array for these formats: 24-bit-per-pixel or 32-bit-per-pixel 

     else 
         pbmi = (PBITMAPINFO) LocalAlloc(LPTR, 
                    sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER)); 

    // Initialize the fields in the BITMAPINFO structure.  

    pbmi->bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER); 
    pbmi->bmiHeader.biWidth = bmp.bmWidth; 
    pbmi->bmiHeader.biHeight = bmp.bmHeight; 
    pbmi->bmiHeader.biPlanes = bmp.bmPlanes; 
    pbmi->bmiHeader.biBitCount = bmp.bmBitsPixel; 
    if (cClrBits < 24) 
        pbmi->bmiHeader.biClrUsed = (1<<cClrBits); 

    // If the bitmap is not compressed, set the BI_RGB flag.  
    pbmi->bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB; 

    // Compute the number of bytes in the array of color  
    // indices and store the result in biSizeImage.  
    // The width must be DWORD aligned unless the bitmap is RLE 
    // compressed. 
    pbmi->bmiHeader.biSizeImage = ((pbmi->bmiHeader.biWidth * cClrBits +31) & ~31) /8
                                  * pbmi->bmiHeader.biHeight; 
    // Set biClrImportant to 0, indicating that all of the  
    // device colors are important.  
     pbmi->bmiHeader.biClrImportant = 0; 
     return pbmi; 
 } 

void CreateBMPFile(LPTSTR pszFile, PBITMAPINFO pbi, 
                  HBITMAP hBMP, HDC hDC) 
 { 
     HANDLE hf;                 // file handle  
    BITMAPFILEHEADER hdr;       // bitmap file-header  
    PBITMAPINFOHEADER pbih;     // bitmap info-header  
    LPBYTE lpBits;              // memory pointer  
    DWORD dwTotal;              // total count of bytes  
    DWORD cb;                   // incremental count of bytes  
    BYTE *hp;                   // byte pointer  
    DWORD dwTmp; 

    pbih = (PBITMAPINFOHEADER) pbi; 
    lpBits = (LPBYTE) GlobalAlloc(GMEM_FIXED, pbih->biSizeImage);

    if (!lpBits) 
         cout << "ERROR:2"; 

    // Retrieve the color table (RGBQUAD array) and the bits  
    // (array of palette indices) from the DIB.  
    GetDIBits(hDC, hBMP, 0, (WORD) pbih->biHeight, lpBits, pbi, 
        DIB_RGB_COLORS);

    // Create the .BMP file.  
    hf = CreateFile(pszFile, 
                   GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 
                   (DWORD) 0, 
                    NULL, 
                   CREATE_ALWAYS, 
                   FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 
                   (HANDLE) NULL); 
    if (hf == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) 
        cout << "ERROR:4"; 
    hdr.bfType = 0x4d42;        // 0x42 = "B" 0x4d = "M"  
    // Compute the size of the entire file.  
    hdr.bfSize = (DWORD) (sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + 
                 pbih->biSize + pbih->biClrUsed 
                 * sizeof(RGBQUAD) + pbih->biSizeImage); 
    hdr.bfReserved1 = 0; 
    hdr.bfReserved2 = 0; 

    // Compute the offset to the array of color indices.  
    hdr.bfOffBits = (DWORD) sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + 
                    pbih->biSize + pbih->biClrUsed 
                    * sizeof (RGBQUAD); 

    // Copy the BITMAPFILEHEADER into the .BMP file.  
    if (!WriteFile(hf, (LPVOID) &hdr, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 
        (LPDWORD) &dwTmp,  NULL)) 
    {
       cout << "ERROR:5";
    }

    // Copy the BITMAPINFOHEADER and RGBQUAD array into the file.  
    if (!WriteFile(hf, (LPVOID) pbih, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER) 
                  + pbih->biClrUsed * sizeof (RGBQUAD), 
                  (LPDWORD) &dwTmp, ( NULL)))
        cout << "ERROR:6";

    // Copy the array of color indices into the .BMP file.  
    dwTotal = cb = pbih->biSizeImage; 
    hp = lpBits; 
    if (!WriteFile(hf, (LPSTR) hp, (int) cb, (LPDWORD) &dwTmp,NULL)) 
           cout << "ERROR:7";

    // Close the .BMP file.  
     if (!CloseHandle(hf)) 
           cout << "ERROR:8"; 

    // Free memory.  
    GlobalFree((HGLOBAL)lpBits);
}

void getBit(string name) {
    int nX = 300;
    int nX2 = 600;
    int nY = 300;
    int nY2 = 700;
     HDC hScrDC  =  GetDC(NULL); 
     HDC hMemDC  =  CreateCompatibleDC(hScrDC);
     int nWidth  =  nX2  -  nX; 
     int nHeight  =  nY2  -  nY; 
     HBITMAP hBitmap  =  CreateCompatibleBitmap(hScrDC,  nWidth,  nHeight); 
     HBITMAP hOldBitmap  =  (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hMemDC,  hBitmap); 

     BitBlt(hMemDC,  0,  0,  nWidth,  nHeight, 
     hScrDC,  nX,  nY,  SRCCOPY); 
     hBitmap  =  (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hMemDC,  hOldBitmap); 
     DeleteDC(hScrDC); 
     DeleteDC(hMemDC); 
    // now your image is held in hBitmap. You can save it or do whatever with it
    PBITMAPINFO pbi = CreateBitmapInfoStruct(hBitmap);
    //File name
    LPTSTR path = L"test.bmp";
    CreateBMPFile(path,pbi,hBitmap,hMemDC);
}

void main(void) {
    getBit("SAVE");
    cout << "Done";
    int wait;
    cin >> wait;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The biggest problem is that `GetDIBits` fails because you're passing a handle to a deleted memory context instead of a handle to a valid device context.  If you fix that, it works.

When debugging, it's always a good idea to check all of the return values.

Other things I've noticed:

1. You should not delete hSrcDC, since you didn't create it.  Use `ReleaseDC`, which is the companion to `GetDC`.
2. Consider using `CAPTUREBLT` in your `BitBlt` call.

Comment: It works for me as well if I move his DeleteDC functions at the end of the getBit routine. I tried to use ReleaseDC but this function takes 2 arguments : ReleaseDC(__in_opt HWND hWnd, __in HDC hDC);  However, in his code he does not declare any HWND variable, so I passed NULL like that and it worked. ReleaseDC(NULL, hScrDC); ReleaseDC(NULL, hMemDC); Is it the proper way to use it in his case?

Comment: @ForceMagic:  ReleaseDC is used to return a DC that you got with GetDC.  GetDC takes an HWND or NULL if you want the DC of the entire screen.  Since he called GetDC with NULL, then it's appropriate to call ReleaseDC(NULL, hSrcDC).  But hMemDC comes from a CreateCompatibleDC call, so DeleteDC is appropriate for that one.